# How to conditionally rename multiple columns of a dataframe using values from a sequence as new variable names?

Tags: r

I would like to use the values of this sequence `seq` to rename the columns `x1` to `x10` of the data frame `df`.

the sequence - variable names to be used

```
var_names<-seq(10, 23.5, 1.5)
```

the data frame, where all variables beginning with `x` are to be renamed by the values of the sequence `var_names`

```
df = 
  data.frame( x1 = rlnorm(10000), x2 = rlnorm(10000), x3 = rlnorm(10000), x4 = rlnorm(10000), x5 = rlnorm(10000), x6 = rlnorm(10000), x7 = rlnorm(10000), x8 = rlnorm(10000), x9 = rlnorm(10000), x10 = rlnorm(10000))
```

my attempt

```
df_renamed <- apply(df, 2, function(x) data.table::setnames(df, old=colnames(x), new=var_names))

## Error in data.table::setnames(df, old = colnames(x), new = var_names) : 
##  'new' is not a character vector
```

expected output

In the output dataframe I want to replace the variable names 
x1 by 10, x2 by 11.5, x3 by 13, x4 by 14.5, x5 by 16, x6 by 17.5, x7 by 19, x8
by 20.5, x9 by 22, x10 by 23.5.

While this replacement of the variable names can be done individually using [this](http://rprogramming.net/rename-columns-in-r/) and other approaches when there are only a few columns, I want a function that does the job efficiently with large datasets using directly the sequence `var_names` and taking advantage of the fact that all variables to be renamed begin with `x`.

Comment: Why don't use `colnames(df) <- var_names` ?

Comment: That gives 'Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [11] must be the same length as the vector [10]'

Comment: It works for me

Comment: let me check again. thanks

Comment: You should have just done `data.table::setnames(df, var_names)`

Comment: Ya. You are right, @DavidArenburg. But for my case that gave the error `Error in data.table::setnames(df, var_names) : Passed a vector of type 'double'. Needs to be type 'character'.` Likely because of the nature of my `var_names` which need to be double for my case in particular. But the solution given below by @kwiscion works fine. In either case, thanks for the input.

Comment: Yes, because it's a really bad practice to set your column names to numbers.

Comment: I agree with you. I am doing only because it is really necessary. It is just a temporary step in the analyses. I will later manipulate further the column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `colnames` can do the job

```
colnames(df) <- var_names
```

Just a remark: It is not the best idea to have numbers as colnames, as it can be confusing and not easy to work with (for example you need to quote such names with ` `)